# In Firestore I need to create multiple records under document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks for your reply. I have one question,

If I check the Firestore Database, I can see three columns, I saw documents of Firestore.

How to create multiple entries under single document ? I want to create as below

```
                                      collection
                                      /         \
                               Document1         Document2
                                /     \            /     \
                            Record1  Record2     Record1 Record2
```

For creating collection, I have used below code , it created collection”testing”, document “subjectID”. I have added fields, f1,f2,f3,f4,f5.

```
            let docRef = this.dbManager.collection('testing').doc(subjectId);
        let setAlan = docRef.set(myEntryEntity.toJSON());


public toJSON(): any {
        let returnJSON = {
            "entry_id": this.entry_id,
            "subject_id": 'Test',
            "entry_date": this.entry_date,
            "questionnaire": this.questionnaire,
            "entry_start_timestamp": this.entry_start_timestamp,
            "entry_end_timestamp": this.entry_end_timestamp,
            "entry_complete": this.entry_complete,
            //"responses": this.responses,
            "last_answered_question" : this.last_answered_question,
            "entry_status" : this.entry_status
        }
        return returnJSON;
    }
```

1)  I am unable to create another record under “subjectID”, It always update the existing “subjectID” record.
2)  How to get all the documents under ‘testing’ collection.

Comment: What is the complete request you are making when trying to update the "subjectId" document?  To get the list of documents, the only way I know is using the REST API: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.list

Comment: Hi Gerardo, i have updated with full values

Comment: You are using the "set" function which will create a new document or overwrite the existing one. You will need to use the "update" function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: Is it possible to create another entry under same document? eg: under document1, field1-->value1,field2-->value1...... another entry under document1, field-->value2,field2-->value2.... IF i get using document "document1", i should get all the values i.e.., value1 and value2.. Is it possible?

Comment: You can have fields that store object types. so you can declare field1:{ 'value' : 'new object' }